# pointwise convergence of $n\sin(n^2x)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Given the sequence of functions $$f_n : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R},f_n(x)  =\left\{\begin{array}{ll} n \sin(n^2x), & 0 ≤ x ≤ \frac{\pi}{n^2},\\ 0, & \text{else.} \end{array}\right.  $$

Examine for pointwise convergence.

I know that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$, but I don't understand why.

In my thinkings $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }f_n$ equals to a factor $n$ which rises continuously multiplied with a value between $[-1,1]$.

Can someone explain how to derive pointwise convergence in this example?

Comment: Fix $x_0$ and let $N$ be such that $\frac{\pi}{N^2} < x_0$, then for any $n>N$, $f_n(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Series or sequence ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe sequence

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The claim is that $f_n \to 0$ point-wise. Let $x_0 \in [0,1]$. If $x_0 = 0$, then we're done. So, we can assume that $x_0 > 0$. Then, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\forall n \geq N: \frac{\pi}{n^2} < x_0$$

This implies that for $n \geq N$, $f_n(x_0) = 0$. But this obviously just means that we have point-wise convergence to $0$ for this sequence of functions so we're done.